# How to create header authorization for API Key define?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, api-key

I can access the api with api-key from postman [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DozOO.png).

But, when I develop into .net core worker service (C#).
I always got unauthorized.

```
userParam.User = userData;
string jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userParam);

HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonUser, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bs-session-id",  this.bs_session_id);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "bs-session-id " +this.bs_session_id);
var result = await client.PostAsync("https://127.0.0.1/api/users", httpContent);
```

Could anybody can help for my issue?
[Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfzAr.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Try add the header as following:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("bs-session-id",this.bs_session_id);
```